# Difference in DateTime.TryParse when running app through SQL Agent and Task Scheduler

Tags: c#, windows-task-scheduler, sql-server-agent

This has got me stumped... I have an application that I run from SQL Server Agent (Operating System cmdExec) that behaves differently to when it's run through Windows Task Scheduler or directly running the exe.

The C# code that fails is this

```
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(StartDate, "dd-MMM-yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dtStart))
```

When running through SQL Agent, it fails and produces a default time, when running through Task Scheduler or running the exe it works.  Nothing has changed on my system or the way the data is being presented to the application.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Should be System.Globilization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

Comment: Are you 100% certain the input is in that format? You don't see 2-digit years much anymore.

Comment: Is it fair to say that by "fails" you mean `TryParseExact` returns `false`? If so, what is the value (from the debugger) of `StartDate` at that moment?

Comment: DStanley - Yes, sure it's 2 digits
@RufusL -  When I run it through VS it works 100% too. It only breaks through SQL Server agent.

The value of StartDate is "3-Nov-22",

Comment: When you say you're running this through SQL Server Agent, is the SQL Server instance running on your local machine or a remote one? If it's remote, that might explain the difference in date formatting

Comment: It's on my local machine @madmonk46

Comment: Hmm, I'd still be interested to see why the format is different then if anyone knows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments, you've stated that the value of `StartDate` is `"3-Nov-22"`. That won't work with the format string `"dd-MMM-yy"`, which requires 2 digits for the day. Changing the format string to `"d-MMM-yy"` should fix your problem. For more information about date/time format strings, please see [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) on the subject.

As for *why* there is a difference in date formatting between the different ways of running the program, I would actually be very interested to see if anyone is able to shed some light on that.

Comment: This works!  Next question - when the 10th comes along, will "dd-MMM-yy" then work and "d-MMM-yy"?

Comment: @NathW for the input "10-Nov-22", both of those format strings will work. The only difference is that "dd-MMM-yy" *requires* the leading 0, whereas "d-MMM-yy" does not. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#dSpecifier) is the specific section of the documentation that defines this

Comment: Awesome, I had a read but missed that bit of the detail :)